# Get path to a file in a bundle with C++ (CFBundleGetMainBundle)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm writing an iOS app which has a C++ component. In order to get the main bundle many other answers recommend using this:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
```

This is fine, but it seems I have to include something like

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

at the top of my file.  But doing this throws a bunch of errors like:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:494:9: Unknown type name 'NSString'
```

I assume this has something to do with my C++ code. I'm wondering if there's something else I can include which doesn't throw this error? If not, what is the right way of accessing the path to a file in the C++ code?

Comment: `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` should be sufficient.

Comment: Note, if you need this in **C** (not ++), click to amazing discussion https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112911/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try including only `CoreFoundation`

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

Or maybe even only `CFBundle`

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBundle.h>
```

Comment: Thanks! `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is due to C's concept of "compilation units". Basically, all headers you include in a source file have to be written in the language of that file. Since both Objective C and C++ are (roughly) supersets of C, you can include C headers (like CoreFoundation) in both C++ and Objective-C source files.

However, a C++ compiler does not know how to read an Objective-C file, and an Objective-C compiler does not know how to read a C++ file, so if you include an Objective-C header like UIKit from a C++ file, the C++ compiler will give you lots of error messages.

To avoid this issue, you should look up the documentation for CFBundle. Turns out, CFBundle is part of CoreFoundation, which is a C API and thus can easily be called from a C++ file, you just have to include the correct header.

While including UIKit might work as well, that is simply a side effect of the fact that some parts of UIKit are based on CoreFoundation, and use it as well, and therefor include CoreFoundation.

However, not all APIs are available as a C version. If you want to call something from UIKit or AVFoundation or so, you may have to create a C "wrapper function" that does what you want to do, and internally is implemented in Objective C. As long as you make sure that only the `.m` implementation file contains Objective-C, and the header file just exposes the function and standard C data types like int or bool, you can then call the function from a C++ application just like you would any other plain C function (which will likely require use of `extern "C"` like it would with regular C).

There is also something called "Objective-C++" (file suffix `.mm`), which is a "pseudo-language" that lets you mix Objective-C and C++ in an implementation file, but even with that you would have to be careful not to expose any of the Objective-C in your header to be able to call it from a plain C++ file.

Answer (score 0):

The point is - when you are trying to `#include` - it considers that code is Native C or C++. If so, you need to tell preprocessor to include it only once by `#ifndef ...`.

If you plan to mix C++ and Objective C code - use `#import` instead of `#include` and you need to rename all files, using this class from `.m` to `.mm` extension.

And the last. I am sure, that `NSString` is a part of `NSFoundation` or `CoreFoundation` that has to be imported - `UIKit` is not responsible for `NSObject` objects.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `CFBundleRef` is not a complete type in C++, this is how I did it:

```cpp
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBundle.h>

std::string get_resources_dir()
{

  CFURLRef resourceURL = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle());
  char resourcePath[PATH_MAX];
  if (CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(resourceURL, true,
                                       (UInt8 *)resourcePath,
                                       PATH_MAX))
  {
    if (resourceURL != NULL)
    {
      CFRelease(resourceURL);
    }
    return resourcePath;
  }
}
```