# in iOS, in pure C, is this the way to get a local file path?

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I need to end up with a cstring ... being the local path to a file in the bundle.

First,

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

(which is pure C right? .. you can't use Foundation)

and then

```
CFBundleRef mb = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef ur = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mb, CFSTR("blah"), CFSTR("txt"), NULL);
CFStringRef imagePath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(ur, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);

CFStringEncoding encodingMethod = CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
const char *filename = CFStringGetCStringPtr(imagePath, encodingMethod);

printf( "\n we did it! .. %s \n", filename );
```

Assuming "blah.txt" is in your bundle, it works.

This is the only way I know to do it - seems long-winded. What's the deal?

1. Is my code long-winded, pansy-assed, and pathetic?
2. Is this is the correct and best idiom to get a cstring path from the filename?

(Note I ***do not want*** to make it an obj-c or obj-cpp file. Pure C.)

Comment: It's not quite clear what the question is here. You have the path at line 2 (`ur`) which is usually what you want, and as a string at line 3 ('imagePath'). Don't forget to `CFRelease` `ur` and `imagePath`. The next two lines aren't related to getting the local file path. Those are trying to convert a CFString to a cstring (though there's no promise that `CFStringGetCStringPtr` will succeed). Is your real question "how do I get cstrings out of CoreFoundation rather than just using CoreFoundation directly?" Yes, entering and leaving CF has some overhead. Generally you should use CF directly.

Comment: For example, if you just want to simply print out the result, `CFShow(ur)` would do that.

Comment: @RobNapier - thanks for those excellent clarifying explanations  :O  Yes, I'm needing a cstring and (in a word) I wondered if I was going about it very poorly ...

Comment: ....... while at the same time, it seemed a bit of a convoluted way to get to a file path.  (I guess, I'm simply "wrong" about that, there's no shorter code.)  Thanks!

Comment: If you need a “native C string representation” e.g. for passing it to system calls (open, rename, ...) then [CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1541515-cfurlgetfilesystemrepresentation) would be the right tool.

Comment: That's a fantastic tip in many situations @MartinR , thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually isn't quite long enough, and has a few minor mistakes:

- You must `CFRelease` all the objects you own. You might be doing this elsewhere, but that's not obvious from the code.
- `CFStringGetCStringPtr` is not promised to return a value. It only returns a value if the string is already internally stored in the format you want. That's *probably* true in this code on every system it would likely actually run on, but it's not safe CoreFoundation practice.
- Similarly, it is not safe to pass the result of `CFStringGetSystemEncoding` to `CFStringGetCStringPtr`, since the latter requires an 8-bit encoding. This isn't promised, but....
- `CFStringGetSystemEncoding` is almost never needed or appropriate anyway. You probably don't actually want MacRoman (which is what you're probably getting, unless you're perhaps configured for MacJapanese). You probably want UTF8, so you should ask for that.

So this is how you would do that:

```
CFBundleRef mb = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef ur = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mb, CFSTR("blah"), CFSTR("txt"), NULL);
CFStringRef imagePath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(ur, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);

// Now convert to a C-string
CFStringEncoding encoding = kCFStringEncodingUTF8;
CFIndex length = CFStringGetLength(imagePath);
CFIndex maxSize = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(length, encoding);

char *filename = (char *)malloc(maxSize + 1); // +1 for \0

// Technically this can fail, but it really, really can't.
CFStringGetCString(imagePath, filename, maxSize, encoding);

printf( "\n we did it! .. %s \n", filename );

// Cleanup
free(filename); filename = NULL;
CFRelease(imagePath); imagePath = NULL;
CFRelease(ur); ur = NULL;
```

You may find the [MYStringConversion](https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch10-CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation/MYStringConversion.c) functions helpful. `MYCFStringCopyUTF8String` returns you a malloc buffer (i.e. you need to `free` it) containing the cstring. (These come from Chapter 10 of iOS Programming: Pushing the Limits.)

One side note on string buffers. People are often tempted to use buffers based on `PATH_MAX`. Keep in mind that macOS permits paths with names much longer than `PATH_MAX`. I'm not aware of any hard limit on the length of a macOS path string. In practice, few real paths exceed `PATH_MAX`, but when you create one, it's entertaining (not actually entertaining) to see how many pieces of software break.

Note that as a rule this code isn't necessary. In most CoreFoundation projects, you just use `ur` directly and it's quite nice compared to working on raw cstrings.